# Inverse Percentages, Percentage issue

Tags: percentages

A house is sold for 457000 dollars , which gives it a profit of 19%, find the profit?

Could you guys please help? i know how to find the original price of something but I'm not sure how to find the profit in this case? it just confuses me a tiny bit could you guys help me answer it?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you have the final price which is $ \$457000$, and you want to find the original price before the $19\%$ profit. This is actually a question of finding the original price of the house and then subtracting the final price from the original price.

Answer (score 0):

Let P be the original price.  The profit is 19% of that or 0.19P.  The total price is then the original price plus that profit: P+ 0.19P= (1.19)P= 475000.